# Is it possible to use the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality on the following sum : $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j}(k-\frac{1}{3})^{j+k}}{j!(j+k)}$

Tags: nt.number-theory

I'm working on a small paper that involves this sum, and I was wondering if you could separate the components of the sum and square them, using the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.

The paper is centered on the approximation of the gamma function, for which this is one of the results, but the sum is somewhat 'intangible' and hard to 'play around with', so I figured maybe finding a way to separate its components would make it easier.

Comment: This sum should not be hard to evaluate explicitly (at least through a recurrence relation). $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j}x^{j+k}}{j!(j+k)}$ is an antiderivative of $x^{k-1} e^{-x}$.

Comment: Wolfram finds the sum is $-\Gamma(k, k - 1/3) + (k-1)!$ where $\Gamma$ is the upper incomplete gamma function. This is probably the simplest expression for the sum

Comment: To elaborate on Brma's answers, you get the following explicit formula for your sum:
$$(k-1)!\left(1-\frac 1{e^{k-\frac 13}}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{(k-\frac 13)^j}{j!}\right).$$
Alternatively you can get an expression as the tail of the Taylor series for the exponential
$$\frac{(k-1)!}{e^{k-\frac 13}}\sum_{j=k}^\infty\frac{(k-\frac 13)^j}{j!}$$
Perhaps one of these expressions is easier to use for your purposes.

Comment: I had tried working around it with the Upper Gamma function definition.. But it just seemed quite hard to work with due to the presence of the partial sum of the taylor $e^x$ series... I noticed when I applied the Cauchy Schwartz inequality... It showed that the above sum squared is lesser or equal to the hurwitz zeta function at s = 2 multiplied by $(k-\frac{1}{3})^{2k}$ multiplied by the modified bessel function of the first kind. I dont know if the results may indicate anything special.. I just found it quite interesting and was wondering if i could play around with them to get more results

Comment: I think you will get better answers if you can explain more exactly what you want to do with this series. Just to say "play around and get more results" is very vague. The Taylor series of the exponential function is an extremely well-known object, so if you ask more specific questions you will probably get an answer.

Comment: Perhaps the simplest formula to use is the integral representation (again as indicated by Bma). Your sum is
$$\int_0^{k-\frac 13}t^{k-1}e^{-t}\,dt.$$

Comment: In short, if I remove the 1/3 and replace it with a constant 'c', that ought to be found, this would be an exact formula for the gamma function divided by 2. I was hoping by finding alternate expressions for the series or bounds, I could get more results about the gamma function itself. For example, I could use this definition simultaneously with that of the riemann zeta functions definition Re(s)>1